# How to change text every few seconds, from a array, using jquery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently working on a project and designing a top navigation bar using Twitter Bootstrap and jQuery. I have a search bar which the user can use do a search query. As you can see below, the "placeholder" has the value "Car". I want jQuery to change the value of "placeholder". jQuery should pick a random value (string) from an array, and while the text changes between x amount of seconds, there should be a smooth transition (fadein and fadeout).

```
<div class="span4">
    <form class="navbar-search input-append">
        <input id="appendedInputButton" type="text" class="input-xlarge" placeholder="Cars">
        <button class="btn" type="button"><i class="icon-search"></i></button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Fading in/out just the placeholder text is going to be tricky, the rest should be straight forward using setInterval and animate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will replace the placeholder every 1 second:

```
$(function() {

   var fonts = ['Times New Roman', 'Arial', 'Tahoma'];
   var time = setInterval(function() {
       var newFont = fonts[Math.floor(Math.random()*fonts.length)];
       $('#appendedInputButton').attr('placeholder', newFont);
   },1000);

});
```

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Jk7ga/). In terms of the fading, you might not be able to recreate the functionality you want. jQuery provide wants of achieve fadeouts, either through [`fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) or [`animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) but they only affect the DOM element itself and one of its CSS properties - not an attribute.

Answer (score 0):

@hohner seems to have done the hard work here! Maybe it's possible to use CSS transitions to handle the fading. I know there will be cross browser issues but it's a start.

Here's a fork of his work with proof of concept where the text colour changes for the second font. http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/qpUN6/

For me this is working in Mac Chrome and Safari. To make the work for all every font change you need to cycle the marker class between two known values. Javascript isn't my strength but I'm sure someone else can take this another step ;)

CSS selectors are like this

```
#appendedInputButton.marker::-webkit-input-placeholder {
color: blue;
}
#appendedInputButton.marker:-moz-placeholder {
color: blue;
}
```

I got this help with selecting the placeholder text from [this source](http://bit.ly/VgpsNc)

and the transitions are the standard

```
#appendedInputButton::-webkit-input-placeholder{
transition: all 2s;
-webkit-transition: all 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
}
```

I slowed it down to 2 sec so you can see what's happening. CSS Transition doesn't work in firefox for me, not sure why.

Good luck